# Unable to remove the unwanted messages(especially Auditbeat) in my centos server

Tags: linux, elasticsearch

I need your help in solving the below mentioned Issue.

I have Installed Auditbeat-7.3.1 as a part of ELK setup in my centos server. Everything was working well, But i was facing problem while deleting the Auditebat Messages which are located under the "/var/log/messages" folder path. These Messages are consuming a lot of space. Its becoming a problem for me to Manually remove the message contents everytime.

Also, I have written a small script which reads these message contents in the specified directory and removes it. But when i Executed the script It was just moving the messages from that file and placing them in another location.

I'm not able to find a solution for this problem.

TIA, For you help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually trying to clean unwanted log entries after they appear, why don't you simply adjust the logging in auditbeat?

The default is `info`, try setting the log level to `error`:

```
logging.level: error
```

There are several other options, such as logging to a different location as referenced [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/auditbeat/current/configuration-logging.html).

I would personally try to exhaust all of them to find a solution rather than writing custom scripts to remove stuff that shouldn't be there to begin with.

Finally, although I don't object to this question being here on U&L, the Elastic stack has a pretty vibrant community:
https://discuss.elastic.co/

Perhaps your question is better suited there?